# Passing unicode string using gsoap

Tags: unicode, multilingual, gsoap

I am sending an response with string response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns3="urn:EVT">
<SOAP-ENV:Header></SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns3:EventsResponse>
<ns3:Result>OK</ns3:Result>
<ns3:Evt ns3:st="0" **
desc=0x0a 0xe3 0x81 0x93 0xe3 0x82 0x93 0xe3 0x81 0xab 0xe3 0x81 0xa1 0xe3 0x81 0xaf>
</ns3:Evt></ns3:GetEventsResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

With the **"desc"** containing the Japanese string encoded in utf-8 and read from an file .

ex: **desc** - 0x0a 0xe3 0x81 0x93 0xe3 0x82 0x93 0xe3 0x81 0xab 0xe3 0x81 0xa1 0xe3 0x81 0xaf

I am directly passing the encoded byte stream in the xml.

**Question:**

1. Am i doing the right thing of passing the values as it is in the buffer "desc"? Please share me an sample xml with multi-language or gsoap example in c.
2. do I need to append &# to the hex value so that XML file can be parsed.
3. Please share me/guide me with an sample xml with Japanese language characters.
4. Besides this have come across an flag "SOAP_C_UTFSTRING" should this be enabled for generating soap xml?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> 4. Besides this have come across an flag "SOAP_C_UTFSTRING" should this be enabled for generating soap xml?

Yes. This flag enables byte strings (`std::string` and `char*`) to contain Unicode as UTF-8 encoded text. Perhaps this flag should be the default.

Alternatively, define wide strings `std::string` and `wchar_t*` to serialize in XML. The Unicode code points are serialized and preserved in XML.

> 2. do I need to append &# to the hex value so that XML file can be parsed.

All strings are serialized in XML by converting them to/from XML. Therefore, no entity encoding is necessary in C/C++ strings.

Literal XML strings are built-in types, referenced as `_XML`. So you could use the `_XML` type that is a `char*` which is literally serialized in XML without translation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alex for your input....

I was able to generate an desired xml with the below changes.  `sample xml= <ns3:GetResponse> desc="こんにちは </ns3:GetResponse>`.

1. Do you still see that I have to move to using wide characters wchar_t*? Won't this require changes to gsoap project (wsdl and dat)?
2. I am still not clear with the string defined with char* how we are able to include hex values greater than 128?
3. Any correction I need to perform to the below code?

> ```
> soap_set_mode(pSoap, SOAP_C_UTFSTRING);
> pSoap->mode |= SOAP_C_UTFSTRING;
> ```

/** Optional attribute 'desc' of XML schema type 'xsd:string' */

```
char *desc;


{           
    FILE *in;
    long lSize;
    size_t result;
    int i;
    
    if ((in = fopen("input.txt","r")) == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    // obtain file size:
    fseek (in , 0 , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell (in);
    rewind (in);
    ns3__GetReponse->mine[i].desc = soap_malloc(pSoap, lSize);
    memset(ns3__GetReponse->mine[i].desc , '\0',lSize );
      
    result = fread (ns3__GetReponse->mine[i].desc,1,lSize,in);
    fclose(in);
}
```

Thanks